# Proof that $\,\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+1}{(3x+1)(5x+1)}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to show that $\;\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^2+1}{(3x+1)(5x+1)}=1$

Note that

$$\left|\frac{x^2+1}{(3x+1)(5x+1)}-1 \right|=\left|\frac{-14x^2-8x}{(3x+1)(5x+1)} \right|=\frac{\left |x \right|\left |14x+8 \right|}{\left |3x+1 \right| \left |5x+1 \right|} $$

It appears that if i take $\delta_{1}=1$ I can easily bound the numerator terms, but it is difficult for me to bound the denominator terms; any suggestions?

Comment: To clarify, do you have to use $\epsilon$-$\delta$? If so, here's a hint: you must avoid the singularities at $x \in \{-1/3, -1/5\}$, so how far away from zero are you allowed to go?

Comment: It's continuous operations on continuous functions in given point, if this is enough argument in your case.

Comment: Well if you can use continuity rules, then the result is immediate from substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $|x|<\frac1{10}$. Then
$$
|5x+1|=5\left|x+\frac15\right|>5\times\frac1{10}=\frac12
$$
and
$$
|3x+1|=3\left|x+\frac13\right|>3\times\frac7{30}=\frac7{10}.
$$
Besides, $|14x+8|<\frac{14}{10}+8<10$, and so
$$
\frac{|14x+8|}{|5x+1||3x+1|}<10\times2\times\frac{10}7=\frac{200}7<30.
$$
Therefore, taking $\delta=\min\left\{\frac1{10},\frac\varepsilon{30}\right\}$ will work.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that
$|x| \leq \frac{1}{10}$ to start.
Then you have that, $|14x+8| \leq \frac{47}{5}$, $\frac{1}{|3x+1|} \leq \frac{10}{7}$ and $\frac{1}{|5x+1|} \leq 2$.
So you have that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, with $|x| \leq \frac{1}{10}$,
\begin{equation}
\left| \frac{x²+1}{(3x+1)(5x+1)}-1 \right| = \frac{|x||14x+8|}{|3x+1||5x+1|} \leq |x|2 \frac{10}{7} \frac{47}{5} = |x|\frac{188}{7}. 
\end{equation}
We can now show that $f : \mathbb{R} \backslash \{\frac{-1}{3},\frac{-1}{5}\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined for each $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{\frac{-1}{3},\frac{-1}{5}\}$ as $f(x) = \frac{x²+1}{(3x+1)(5x+1)}$ as a limit $1$, evaluated in $0$. 
Let $\epsilon > 0$, with $\delta = \frac{7}{188} \epsilon $, we have that for each $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{\frac{-1}{3},\frac{-1}{5}, 0\}$, with $|x-0| \leq \delta$ and $|x-0| \leq \frac{1}{10}$,
\begin{equation}
\left| \frac{x²+1}{(3x+1)(5x+1)}-1 \right| = \frac{|x||14x+8|}{|3x+1||5x+1|} \leq |x|\frac{188}{7} \leq \delta \frac{188}{7} = \epsilon. 
\end{equation}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).